# How do I pass arbitrary variables to Paypal and have them returned?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I need to pass *arbitrary* variables to Paypal and then have them returned to my "thank you" page (the page that I have Paypal return to after checkout is complete)

My intent is to

1. Have the customer fill out a form (at my site)
2. Have the customer go through paypal (at paypal)
3. Have the customer's information entered into my database (at my site)

I have learned how to get Paypal to redirect back to my site. However I don't know how to get it to pass arbitrary variables of my choosing.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.michaelsherron.com/paypal-IPN-custom-variables

Comment: The linked info is good - but the sample script will cause you some headaches by now - would suggest looking at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples for inspiration. Documentation is available under https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/